# Rails Model Categorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have two columns in my database `first_name` and `last_name` which I want to condense into one category `name`. 
User Model:

```
def name
    @name ||= Name.new(first_name, last_name)   
end
def name=(name)
    self[:first_name] = name.first_name
    self[:last_name] = name.last_name
    @name = name

end
```

And Name Class

```
class Name
attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name, @last_name = first_name, last_name
end
```

end

Then for the view:

```
= @product.user.name
```

But then when the page is displayed I get this `#<Name:0x007fd8b5ec1d10>`
instead of the first and last name I get in the console.
Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Name` class should implement `to_s` method to be displayed properly in view:

```
class Name
  # ...

  def to_s
    "#@first_name #@last_name"
  end
end
```